# Biological Nitrogen Fixation

Tags: biochemistry, botany, plant-physiology

I just studied Biological Nitrogen Fixation and saw it's reaction but i do not understand why there is 8 electrons and 8 protons are involved and Hydrogen molecule is formed side by side along with 2xAmmonia... According to me there should be 6electrons and protons because it needs 2electons in each step from Nitrogen to Di-imide and 2electrons from Di-imide to Hydrazine to give out 2xAmmonia

Comment: The reason why two additional electrons are required is to reduce two additional hydrogen ions to one molecule of hydrogen gas, as any text book account makes cleaer e.g. [Berg *et. al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22522/)  Are you asking why this latter occurs, when it seems unnecessary? The absence of an explanation in such texts tells its own story.